# Google map with multiple annotations

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am new to google maps I followed the following tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker When I try to display multiple annotations using for loop I get the out put with a single annotation. The following is my code,

```
for (int i = 0; i < [ARR count]; i++)
{
  float latitude_val = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[ARR objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"lat"]] floatValue];
  float longitude_val = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[ARR:i] valueForKey:@"lng"]] floatValue];            
  GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
  marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude_val, longitude_val);           
  marker.map = _mapView;      
}
```

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191436/adding-multiple-pins-on-google-map-in-ios

Comment: check url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27163318/how-to-show-multiple-annotation-in-mkmapview-ios

Comment: Is the following lines are mandatory [mkr setTitle:<Title>];
        [mkr setSnippet:<Snippet>]; . If so my out pout shows a single annotation

Comment: @Lalitkumar I tried changing float to double but still single annotation is displayed

Comment: @Jayasabeen can you print the values of `ARR` lat & lng values and add those lat,lng values with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one.. it is working fine for me. i hope it will help you also.

```
 GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:[[[ARR objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"lat"] floatValue]  longitude:[[[ARR objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"lng"] floatValue] zoom:15];

 GMSMapView *googleMapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height) camera:camera];
  googleMapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
  googleMapView.delegate = self;

[your_Array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *thumbnailDict, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[thumbnailDict valueForKey:@"lat"] floatValue],[[thumbnailDict valueForKey:@"lng"] floatValue]);
  //  marker.title = [thumbnailDict valueForKey:@"title"];
  //  marker.snippet = @"Snippet";
    marker.map = googleMapView;
  //  marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Map_Annotation"];

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Setup the `GMSMapView` and `GMSCameraPosition`

```
-(void)setup {
 GMSCameraPosition *camera =
 [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:71.00
                            longitude:45.124
                                 zoom:14
                              bearing:0
                         viewingAngle:0];

 self.mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake() camera:camera];
 self.mapView.delegate = self;
 self.mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal;
 //current location on map
 self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
 //map controls
 self.mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;
 self.mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
 //constraining the zoom options
 [self.mapView setMinZoom:10 maxZoom:18];
 [self.view addSubview:self.mapView];
}
```

Call this method for ploting `multiple pins` on map.

```
-(void)plotMutliplePinsOnMap:(NSArray *)mapArray
{
   for(int i=0;i<[mapArray count];i++)
   {
    double_lat = [[[mapArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
    double_long = [[[mapArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];

    GMSMarker *mkr = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    mkr.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_black"];
    if (double_lat !=0 && double_long!=0)
    {
        [mkr setPosition:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(double_lat, double_long)];
        [mkr setTitle:[[mapArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"placeName"]];
        [mkr setSnippet:[[mapArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"address"]];
        [mkr setMap:self.mapView];

        GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:double_lat longitude:double_long zoom:5];
        self.mapView.camera=camera;
    }
  }
}
```